# Opencart, hook function into successful order

Tags: php, opencart

I created a custom extension for opencart that aggregates products from external sources. Each external product has a prefix in the model number. I want to create some custom actions when a user purchases one of these products. But I don't know OC well enough to know where to look for the function that's responsible for handling new orders.

Can someone point me to the file and function that gets called when an order is successfully paid for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file that processes the orders is in:

```
catalog/model/checkout/order.php
```

This is the file that adds the order information into the database and sends the order email to the store owner and the customer

this is called from the confirm controller which is located at:

```
catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php
```

The following line loads the order.php file:

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
```

The function that calls it is the following line

```
$this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($data);
```

and the function it calls in the order.php file (as the above line suggests) is:

```
public function addOrder($data) {
```

I hope this helps